# Solve $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}$ without Taylor expansion or any expansion.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

> Evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}$ without Taylor, Mclauren or any expansion..

So I know that $$f(x)=e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

around $0$ and for $x=1$ we have that: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}=e$, but however can you solve it without any expansion?

Comment: Well, first you've got a problem of what $e$ is. Nowadays most people define $e$ to be $e = \exp(1) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}$. Of course there are other ways to define it, but you need to specify how you are defining it.

Comment: What kind of answer could one expect to such a question? A limit? Certainly not any algebraic expression since $e$ is transcendental

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can look up at the Proof Wiki. There is an arcticle, to be precise [this one](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Number:_Limit_of_Sequence_implies_Limit_of_Series/Proof_1), which provides a proof of the equivalence of the limit and the series represantation of $e$.

---

As achille hui pointed out the linked proof has got a little problem. As it is said at the bottom of the Proof Wiki page:

> *This article, or a section of it, needs explaining, namely:*
>
> ***Wait! That's invoking $\lim \sum=\sum\lim$ tacitly. Us sneaky bastards!***
>
> *You can help Pr$\infty$fWiki by [explaining it](https://proofwiki.org/w/index.php?title=Euler%27s_Number:_Limit_of_Sequence_implies_Limit_of_Series/Proof_1&action=edit). To discuss this point in more detail, feel free to use the talk page.
> If you are able to explain it, then when you have done so you can remove this instance of {{Explain}} from the code.*

Therefore the proof is not completely reliable.

Comment: Hmm... the proof in your link is broken. It implicitly assume $\lim \sum = \sum \lim$ and this sort of exchange of sum and limit can fail...

Comment: To be honest I was not aware of this. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: You should keep this answer but point out that proof has some problem. (That proof is fixable - one can use the sequence version of [Tonelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem#The_Fubini%E2%80%93Tonelli_theorem) to justify the exchange)

Answer (score 0):

You give us an infinite series and ask to evaluate it without any "expansion". This sounds a little contradictory.

As this rules out any alternative definition of $e$ (a transcendental number, which is hard to express with finite means), all we can do is

- prove convergence of the series (growing and bounded by $1+\sum_{k=0}^\infty2^{-k}=3$);
- evaluate approximations as tight as one wants by estimating the value of the tail.

E.g.,

$$1+1+\frac12+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}<e<1+1+\frac12+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!}+\frac3{5!}$$

because

$$\frac{5!}{5!}+\frac{5!}{6!}+\frac{5!}{7!}+\cdots<\frac1{0!}+\frac1{1!}+\frac1{2!}+\cdots=e<3$$